Shallow well pump trips breaker
and thank you in advance for any assistance. It is greatly appreciated. The situation is, I have a pump house with a 1/2HP shallow well pump. The pump house has an outlet that the pump is plugged into on a dedicated breaker (30amp). I purposely turned water on 2-3 times so pump would kick on to refill tank and breaker didnt trip so I dont know how many cycles it takes before the breaker finally trips. Trying to brainstorm on what the problem could be I got tired of the breaker tripping so I ran an extension cord from an outside outlet (on a 15 or 20 amp breaker which also has indoor home lights and outlets) to the pump house and plugged in the pump and that breaker has never tripped with all the lights, outlets and pump on that breaker.
I thought maybe the pump house outlet was bad so I changed the outlet, same problem. When anything else (lights, fan, tools) is plugged into the outlet in the pump house, the breaker never trips. It only trips with the pump.
I was also wondering if I could connect the pump to a light switch to shut it off when not needed instead of turning breaker off/on all the time. The well is used for outdoor spigots only, so it isnt used all the time.
Thanks,
Alex

The pump motor or bearings may be starting to fail, and sometimes seizing. A motor which is not permitted to turn may draw a great deal more current then it will under normal operation, up to and including a near short circuit. I would be exploring that option, trying to find a way to isolate the problem.

a surface pump or is in in the well?

What kind of breaker trip - overcurrent, AFCI or GFCI?

Your second question (about a switch) should be presented as a separate question, but see NEC 430.109(C) https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#430.109_(C)

So the pump trips the 30 amp breaker, but does not trip a 15 amp breaker when use on an extension cord.
Logic would say the breaker is malfunctioning. Breakers are relatively cheap.  I would change the breaker.  However first check all connections at the breaker in the box and at the outlet. There could be a loose connection. ( Had this exact issue and the problem was a loose wire nut.)
